# ZfcRbac or BjyAuthorize or both to be used?

Tags: zend-framework2, acl, bjyauthorize, zfc-rbac

I am working on a Zendframework 2 project. I need to implement access control in to my application. This is my first time with zf. When I investigated about ACL i came across 2 modules `ZfcRbac` and `BjyAuthorize`. I am confused.

My Question is `Should I use these both or either?`

*ADDITIONAL* : If either, If any body know any blog post or article comparing the pros and cons of both, please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you with your decision:
[Instant ACLs with Zend Framework 2](http://de.slideshare.net/stefanovalle/instant-acls-with-zend-framework-2)